# Request modification with service worker fetch listener

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am trying to add a custom header on all network requests going from application and I am trying to do this via service worker fetch. 
The content of header needs to come from app(client), so I need to wait for a response from client before responding to any event.
Below is my attempt to achieve this

Here is my fetch listener code

```
function send_message_to_client(client, msg){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var msg_chan = new MessageChannel();

        msg_chan.port1.onmessage = function(event){
            if(event.data.error){
                reject(event.data.error);
            }else{
                resolve(event.data);
            }
        };

        client.postMessage("SW Says: '"+msg+"'", [msg_chan.port2]);
    });
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {

    event.waitUntil(async function () {
        const client = await clients.get(event.clientId);
        send_message_to_client(client, "Pass Transaction Details")
            .then(function (m) {
                var req = new Request(event.request.url, {
                    method: event.request.method,
                    headers: event.request.headers,
                    mode: 'same-origin',
                    credentials: event.request.credentials,
                    redirect: 'manual'
                });

                var res_obj = JSON.parse(m);
                req.headers.append('MY_CUSTOM_HEADER', res_obj.hdr_val);
                return event.respondWith(fetch(req));

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error after event.respondWith call");
                console.log(error);
            });

    }());
});
```

and here is how I registered this worker and its message listener

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/my-sw.js', {scope: '/'})
    .then(function(reg) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
            var msg_reply = {
                "message" : "Replying to SW request",
            };
            msg_reply.hdr_val = sessionStorage.getItem('__data_val');
            console.log("Replying with "+ JSON.stringify(msg_reply));
            e.ports[0].postMessage(JSON.stringify(msg_reply));

        };
    }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
});
```

but apparently its shooting 2 requests, 1 original request and 1 with modified headers.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ? I am a newbie in javascript so pardon me if there is some stupid mistake.

From service worker debug console, I found that its going in catch block right after event.respondWith() call, so something wrong there probably ?

Answer (score 1):

You must call `FetchEvent.respondWith()` synchronously in your fetch handler.  In your code you are calling `waitUntil()` synchronously, but calling `respondWith()` later.  By not calling `respondWith()` before returning from the fetch handler you are telling the browser to continue on with its normal networking path without interception.

I think you want something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    // call respondWith() here
    event.respondWith(async function () {
        const client = await clients.get(event.clientId);
        send_message_to_client(client, "Pass Transaction Details")
            .then(function (m) {
                var req = new Request(event.request.url, {
                    method: event.request.method,
                    headers: event.request.headers,
                    mode: 'same-origin',
                    credentials: event.request.credentials,
                    redirect: 'manual'
                });

                var res_obj = JSON.parse(m);
                req.headers.append('MY_CUSTOM_HEADER', res_obj.hdr_val);
                // just return the response back to the respondWith() here
                return fetch(req);

            })
            // You probably want to add a .catch() to return some reasonable fallback
            // response.
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.